# Multiple dockers and multiple domains on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have 10 low-traffic websites, all with different domains and I want to run all of them on one elastic beanstalk environment.

I'm a developer with zero experience with docker but from reading other answers I got the idea that a multicontainer docker environment could be what I need.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html

Can someone who have done it before (multiple domains on an EB environment) confirm that I'm on the right direction? If so, is there somewhere a tutorial on doing a multi-domain environment for people who never used docker?

Answer (score 2):

AWS EB doesn't handle routing based on domain names. You can expose multiple ports. 80 and 9000 are exposed in the graphic below. But the visitor must type to port into the url, that's very ugly. [image]

In order to route traffic to a container based on the domain you need a proxy. [Nginx Proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) can do that for you.